# PHP Search function string to number conversion (search for month)

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

In Laravel, I am using the following code in my EventsController:

```
public function index()
{
    $search     = Input::get('search');

    $searchResult   = Events::orderBy($order, $by)->where(function ($query) use ($search)
        {
            $query->where('name', 'LIKE', '%'. $search .'%')
            ->orWhere('date', 'LIKE', '%'. $search .'%')->get();
        })->Paginate(10);

    $search         = str_getcsv($search, ' ');

    if (in_array("january", $search)) {
        $searchResult   = Events::orderBy($order, $by)->where('date', 'LIKE', '%2015-01'%')->Paginate(10);
    }
    if (in_array("february", $search)) {
        $searchResult   = Events::orderBy($order, $by)->where('date', 'LIKE', '%2015-02'%')->Paginate(10);
    }
        return View::make('events.index')
        ->with('events', $searchResult)
        ->with('search', $search);
}
```

The code is actually working but ofcourse this is bad practice. I store dates in my database like below:

2015-07-30 (Y-m-d)

What I want to accomplish is, when I search for "january" in my search, it should show all results from january (2015-01-xx). Same for february, and so on.

With the above code I could accomplish this, but I need to copy the same code for all 12 months. This isn't good. Any help on making the code better for this purpose? Any other tips or tricks? I am posting this just for learning purposes.

Issue #2. I want to be able to search for "1 january" for example. Any help or advice on how to accomplish this?

Comment: About issue #2 - won't where('date','2015-01-01') won't work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest way to get rid of the IFs could be introducing mapping between month names and the month number, e.g.:

```
$month = 'january'; // february, march, ...
$monthNumber = date('m', strtotime($month);
$searchResult   = Events::orderBy($order, $by)->where('date', 'LIKE', '%2015-' . $monthNuber . '%')->Paginate(10);
```

Comment: So simple, didn't think about this yet... Thanks for the tip :)